# Using a Wildcard after a Like when using params.has_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filtering, wildcard, parameters

I have a search field filter on a docket_id  or address like with wildcards before and after, on an orders table as below:-

```
if params.has_key?("docket_id_filter")
  @orders = @orders.where("docket_id like ? OR address like ?", "%#{params[:docket_id_filter]}%", "%#{params[:docket_id_filter]}%")
end
```

I have a problem when users copy and paste a value in the search field with a "carriage return" or space after the number.

This returns no values as it doesn't match the criteria.

The code running on Rails for a correct search is as below:-

```
Started GET "/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&docket_id_filter=6140132790&state_filter=All&day_filter%5Bday%5D=&commit=Filter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-09 16:09:22 +0800
```

while one with an space after it, is as below:-

```
Started GET "/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&docket_id_filter=6140099196 &state_filter=All&day_filter%5Bday%5D=&commit=Filter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-09 16:13:45 +0800
```

How can I do a check to see the last character to exclude it? Do i use a ends_with or is there a way to ignore it or format the search field before running the code.

or

Can i check the last character and give an error pop-up msg?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! :-)

```
if params.has_key?("docket_id_filter")
    if "docket_id_filter".last(0) == ''
        @orders = @orders.where("docket_id like ?", "%#{params[:docket_id_filter].first(10)}%")
    else
        @orders = @orders.where("docket_id like ? OR address like ?", "%#{params[:docket_id_filter]}%", "%#{params[:docket_id_filter]}%")
  end
end
```